# How to get Centos security update notice?

Tags: centos, centos7

My system is centos 7.4.

As I know, RED HAT has [security-updates notice](https://access.redhat.com/security/security-updates/#/).

I want to know where can I get the Centos security update notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick google search for `centos security announcments` yields this result:

https://lists.centos.org/mailman/listinfo/centos-announce

After subscribing you can elect to only receive security announcements in the mailinglist options :

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. Changed the answer for CentOS, which is basically the same.